# Not able to display icons and texts in Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4, font-awesome-5

I am trying to display the brand logo followed by a compact disk image along with some text.
Problem is the code for displaying icon followed by text works everywhere other than in the  tag

This is my code. I am using Django in the backend.

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'music/style.css' %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-Bfad6CLCknfcloXFOyFnlgtENryhrpZCe29RTifKEixXQZ38WheV+i/6YWSzkz3V" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!--Header-->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'music:index' %}">JBox</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <!-- Items -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'music:index' %}">
                        <i class="fa fa-compact-disk"></i>
                        Albums
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>

{% if all_albums %}
<h3>All Albums:</h3>
    <ul>
        {% for album in all_albums %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'music:detail' album.id %}">{{album.album_title}}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <h3>You don't have any albums</h3>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok with a lot of digging around I found out my problem. In Bootstrap 4.4.1 the navbar becomes a collapsable if `navbar-expand-sm` or any other dynamic class is added.

So to fix my problem,
**Change:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
```

**To:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-primary">
```

Answer (score 0):

Like in the [description of FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons/compact-disc?style=solid) you have to use the `fas` class for the compact-disk like this

```
<i class="fas fa-compact-disc"></i>
```

Comment: unfortunately even that doesn't work, also the problem I am facing is that not just the icon but also the text is not shown. This issue occurs only in the navbar.

Comment: Okay, could you please create a fiddle with the the styles to reproduce the missing icon? I have tested your example with the `fas` class and it works. It could be that the error cames from your `music/style.css`